# Is it possible to implement method analogical to subList(a,b) but that works when a>b?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I would like to implement a method analogical to subList(a,b), but that works when a>b. subList(a,b) and subList(b,a) should return List view of the same scope, however differently iterated and numerated. The *view* in case of a>b should be reversed. Is it possible?

My solution as for now is pretty primitive. The first problem is that a subList(a,b) in case for a>b doesn't adjust numbering accordingly (for `remove` or `get` methods usage). But what is more important, the reversed List view is actually a copy here not an actual view and I have no idea how to fix even that.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ReverseLinkedList <T> extends LinkedList<T>
{
    ReverseLinkedList(final List<T> l)
    {
        super(l); // problem, I want a view not a copy
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<T>()
        {
            ListIterator<T> listIter = listIterator(size());
            public boolean hasNext() 
            { 
                return listIter.hasPrevious(); 
            }
            public T next() 
            { 
                return listIter.previous(); 
            }
            public void remove() 
            { 
                listIter.remove(); 
            }  
        };
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CleverList<T> extends LinkedList<T>
{
    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        if ( fromIndex < toIndex )
        {
            return super.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ReverseLinkedList<T>(super.subList(toIndex-1,fromIndex-1));
        }
    }
}
```

How it works as for now:

```
    CleverList<Integer> list = new CleverList<Integer>();
    for ( int i=1; i<=10; ++i )
    {
        list.add(i);
    }
    List<Integer> listA = list.subList(2,8);
    printList(listA);
    // "3 4 5 6 7 8 " ok
    List<Integer> listB = list.subList(8,2);
    printList(listB);
    // "7 6 5 4 3 2 " ok

    listB.remove(2);
    printList(listB);
    // "7 6 5 3 2 " not ok, the point was to remove "5"
    printList(list);
    // "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 " not ok, nothing was removed
```

Comment: Does your class have to extend a `LinkedList` or can it just implement a `List`?

Comment: @user2040251 I think List would be sufficient. I'm a bit curious about LinkedList extension though.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use composition instead of inheritance. It can look like this:

```
class ReverseLinkedList<T> implements List<T> {
    // A reference to the actual list.
    private final List<T> list;

    public ReverseLinkedList(final List<T> list) {
        // Does not create a copy.
        // Stores a reference to the original list instead.
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override 
    public T get(int index) {
        // Adjusts the index and calls the method on an actual list.
        return list.get(list.size() - 1 - index);
    }

    //And so on for all the other methods declared in the List interface...

}
```

It does exactly what you need: it doesn't create a copy of the list passed to the constructor and you can control all the methods(get, remove etc.) to adjust the index properly. The disadvantage of this approach is the amount of code you need to write: each method declared in the `List` interface must be defined in the `ReverseLinkedList` class.

Comment: Yes that's the best solution. It also gives you full control over whether you want this as a read-only view or a write-through view of the original list. If you do not need a view, but a copy will do, you could go for `List<X> reverse = original.clone(); Collections.reverse(reverse);`.

Comment: and what about interator() and listIterator() methods? could you suggest their implementations?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous Almost the same way as the other methods: create an iterator of an actual list and then use previous  to implement next(and vice verse), hasPrevious for hasNext and adjust index for all operations that involve index.